# How do I return the value of an array of flags from a countdown timer in Android Studio?

Tags: java, countdowntimer, flags

I have a count down timer, inside it it is the onTick method and inside that method there are several if statements. Now if I have set the flag array values in those if statements and want to return the value of the flags and check for them when I click a button, how do I do that?

```
the array ---> int [] flag = {0,0,0}
the timer --->  

private void startTimer() {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered startTimer() method");
        millisInFuture = mTimeLeftInMillis;
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
                final long millisPassed = millisInFuture - mTimeLeftInMillis;
                progress = (int) (millisPassed * 100 / millisInFuture);
                pb.setProgress(progress);
                pb2.setProgress(0);
                pb3.setProgress(0);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Key: 60 sec
                if (millisInFuture == 480000) {
                    if (millisPassed <= 60000 || (millisPassed > 180000 && millisPassed <= 240000) || (millisPassed > 300000 && millisPassed <= 360000 || (millisPassed > 420000 && millisPassed <= 480000))) {
//                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//                        stepupimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the first if statement of key 60 is entered");
                        statusIfUp();
                        flag[0] = 1;
                        //stageUp(stageTime[0]);
                        upArrowAnimation();
                    } else if ((millisPassed > 60000 && millisPassed <= 180000)) {
//                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//                        stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the second if statement of key 60 is entered");
                        statusIfDown();
                        flag[0] = 0;
                        flag[1] = 1;
                        flag[2] = 0;
                       // stageDown(stageTime[1]);
                        downArrowAnimation();
                    } else if ((millisPassed > 240000 && millisPassed <= 300000) || (millisPassed > 360000 && millisPassed <= 420000)){
//                        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//                        stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
                        Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the first if statement of key 60 is entered");
                        statusIfDown();
                        flag[0] = 0;
                        flag[1] = 0;
                        flag[2] = 1;
                      //  stageDown(stageTime[2]);
                        downArrowAnimation();
                    }

                }

            @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            pb.setProgress(100); pb2.setProgress(0); pb3.setProgress(0);
            stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            stage_timer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            avd1.stop(); avd2.stop(); avd3.stop(); avd4.stop();
            //Vibration
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(150, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                Toast.makeText(tool1mode1.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(new long[]{150}, new int[]{VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK}, -1));
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Now when I click the button inside its onClick method I call the startTimer() method to start my timer. What I want is to check the flag value while this timer is working, and based on the flag value I will call a method that I will pass a value to. The flags act as signals for a lack of better word. So how do I return the flag values in the onTick method inside the timer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a callback. One simple way of doing that is by creating an `Interface`:

```
public interface Execute {

    public void doExecute(int[] flags);

}
```

And then call your `StartTimer` method with a new `Execute` like so:

```
private void testMethod() {
    startTimer(new Execute(){

        @Override
        public void doExecute( int[] flags ) {
            // do something with your flags here
        }
    });
}
```

So add the `Execute` object as a parameter to the `StarTimer` method:

```
 private void startTimer( Execute execute ) {
        Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "CHECK","Entered startTimer() method");
        //etc..
```

And finally run the `doExecute` method from `startTimer` when you want. For example:

```
} else if ((millisPassed > 240000 && millisPassed <= 300000) || (millisPassed > 360000 && millisPassed <= 420000)){
//  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(tool1mode1.this, R.anim.fade_in);
//  stepdownimage.setAnimation(animation);
    Log.println(Log.ASSERT,"CHECK","Check that the first if statement of key 60 is entered");
    statusIfDown();
    flag[0] = 0;
    flag[1] = 0;
    flag[2] = 1;
    //  stageDown(stageTime[2]);
    downArrowAnimation();
    execute.doExecute(flag); // <-- run  
}
```